# Can you show the hostname on the Windows Server 2008 login screen?

Tags: windows-server-2008

Is it possible to show the hostname of the computer on the Windows Server 2008 login screen?

Comment: Are you looking to permanently show the hostname? If not, you can get the hostname by typing .\ in the username box.  This will start a local logon and where it normally says "Log on to: DOMAIN" it will display the hostname.

Comment: I would prefer to permanently show the hostname to match our Linux servers.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, you can use the BGInfo utility to do this, by setting it as the login screen background.  I've only ever used BGInfo as wallpaper, so that I know which server I'm RDP-ed into, but there's a guide available at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897557.

Answer (score 2):

If you do Switch User->Other User and click on the link that says "How do I logon to another domain?" it will give you the hostname there.

Answer (score 2):

In the username field if you type a `.` it will show the local machine name below the password prompt.

It's also a good shortcut to logging in locally on a domain (eg `.\administrator` )